# setting screenOrientation to portrait doesn't work

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I want to run my app in portrait mode, I'm aware this isn't best practice but there are reasons to do this. and while I have disabled the rotation it still is able to rotate on some views will it doesn't on others.

I have this part of code in my Android Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name="<name>.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|keyboard|locale|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

I'm using fragments to show different containers depending on user input.

this is the only activity that has fragments.
I have tried a few solutions on this site. including setting portrait mode on by code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it something like below.

After rootView in your java add this line

```
 getActivity().setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  // programmatically
```

For example:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activityxml, container, false);       
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

And also in your manifest change it:

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

as

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" >
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 <activity android:name="com.myActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                >
            </activity>
```

Comment: this has no changes on the behavior from the app. but thnx for the input.

Answer (score 0):

use below code before super.onCreate.first line of code.it force activity to portrait(of course both side of portrait)

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

the code that you entered android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" just force activity to don't miss it's stats on rotate(onCreate call just once and if rotate onPause will call)

Answer (score 0):

add Android Manifest:

```
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```